# Как создать новую учётную запись на Windows 7, чтобы из этой учётки были доступны только определённые программы?

Tags: windows, пк

Полагаю, вы поняли. Т. е. у меня есть уч. запись с паролем, установлено множество программ и нужно создать другую уч. запись, из которой будут доступны только те программы, которые я хочу сделать доступными на учётке без пароля. Возможно ли такое? А если именно так нельзя, то какие есть, так сказать, близкие решения?

Comment: https://pikabu.ru/story/zakruchivaem_gayki_polzovatelyam_chast_1_politika_ogranichennogo_ispolzovaniya_programm_6503155